# Convert.FromBase64String() Does not function correctly

Tags: c#, base64

In the example below why is the Convert.FromBase64String() not throwing an exception. Surely it should be throwing a format exception?

```
string s = "This is just a test string which we will test if it is base64";

bool isBase64 = false;

try
{
     byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
     isBase64 = true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      isBase64 = false;
}
```

Comment: As fejesjoco points out, that's a valid base64 string. It's equivalent to `{ 78, 24, 172, 138, 200, 238, 178, 214, 173, 122, 203, 108, 182, 184, 167, 131, 8, 98, 114, 28, 30, 194, 41, 101, 181, 235, 45, 137, 248, 173, 138, 198, 218, 177, 238, 184 }`

Answer (score 9):

First of all, whenever you think the framework is broken, think again, and again, because it's rarely the case, especially with such a basic and old function.

This is actually a perfectly valid base64 string. Whitespace is optional and ignored. Then you get "Thisisjustateststringwhichwewilltestifitisbase64". The length happens to be divisible by 4, and it contains only letters and numbers. There's no reason why you would think it's invalid.

Comment: [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: +1 for `think again, and again...` That's all we need.